# Android list items overlap listview borders

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working with the simple ListView. Need to make this ListView round (not the every list item round, but the ListView itself). So for this purpose I use shape xml-file. It looks like that:

[image]

The problem appears when I need to change color of the items. This color overlaps border of the listview. And it looks something like that:

[image]

As you can see, the listView is square again, not rounded. How can I prevent this? Couldn't found the solution though it seems a pretty much common thing to me.

Comment: it is a hack. You can add a padding from top and bottom in your list view. Try using the corner radius as the value of padding.
Also add a padding of 1dp from left and right for extra black outline.

Comment: @mudit Add padding as a value of padding? What do you mean by that? Just add "padding" option in shape xml-file?

Comment: add padding in your listview xml file, not in your shape file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add space around you list item add in you list item layout..

```
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
android:paddingLeft="2dp";
android:paddingBottom="2dp";
```

or

```
android:padding="2dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use padding in listview..

```
android:padding="5dp"
```